# SOAP UI: Using a value from XML for a service request

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy

Can some explain the best way on SOAP UI Free to achieve the below scenario

Load the response value from one Test Case Web service as a request value on second Test Case Web service.

in Test case 1 Script Assertion

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def respXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())
respXmlHolder.declareNamespace("ns1","http://www.moj.com/api/services/checkout")
def finsess = respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns1:sessresp/ns1:sessionId")
log.info finsess
```

> Log Info shows below 70c8a6f80b6ff0c72502

Now how to automatically load this above sessionid onto Test Case 2 Web Service as shown below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://www.moj.com/api/services/final">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:FinSessionRequest>
         <typ:correlationId>1234</typ:correlationId>
         <typ:sessionId>70c8a6f80b6ff0c72502</typ:sessionId>
         <typ:username>abcd</typ:username>
         <typ:password>1234</typ:password>
      </typ:FinSessionRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Property transfer test step** for this task, without Groovy scripting. See more at [SoapUI docs](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html). You just pick the source XML element with XPath and similarly the target element. SoapUI will do the replacement when you execute the test step (or the test case). I recommend to use this way as it is transparent.

If you really need to transfer the value with Groovy scripting, you can set a test suite property value in your assertion script:

```
def testSuite = context.getTestCase().getTestSuite()
testSuite.setPropertyValue("MyId", finsess)
```

And then place the *MyId* into your request message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://www.moj.com/api/services/final">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:FinSessionRequest>
         <typ:correlationId>1234</typ:correlationId>
         <typ:sessionId>${#TestSuite#MyId}</typ:sessionId>
         <typ:username>abcd</typ:username>
         <typ:password>1234</typ:password>
      </typ:FinSessionRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This works as long as the two test cases belong to the same test suite.

Karel